# How would I implement a random.choice() like function which returns reproducible results?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'd like to pass a fixed seed (string) to a function, and then have it randomly select one item from a list. However, it should be the same item from the same list if the same seed it used! Obviously this isn't random at all, but it should more or less appear to be random and be about equally distributed. It must be quite fast too.

To demonstrate, this is how random works.

```
>>> random.seed('Python')
>>> random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
3
>>> random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
6
>>> random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
2
```

What I'd like is this.

```
>>> notrandom([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],seed='Python')
4
>>> notrandom([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],seed='Python')
4
>>> notrandom([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],seed='Python')
4
```

It only needs to be reproducible if the same list is used with the same seed string.

Comment: This works so long as you re-seed `random` before every choice, which you aren't doing here.

Comment: 4.  chosen by fair dice roll.  guaranteed to be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Python doc for random](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html), I think this is what you are looking for:

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden
>   instance of the random.Random class. You can instantiate your own instances
>   of Random to get generators that don’t share state.

Like,

```
> r = random.Random()

> r.seed('Hi')
> r.random()
0.3787897089299177

> r.seed('Hi')
> r.random()
0.3787897089299177
```

Comment: This will result in the same index being chosen for different lists of the same length (and generally the index being predictable for all lists if you know which was chosen for any list for a given seed) so you need to do something extra with the seed if you want different picks for different lists.

Comment: This is quite slow as seeding Python's PRNG involves filling 2.5 KiB of state with data and the default version 2 algorithm of `seed()` applies SHA512 to the UTF-8 encoded version of the seed string.

Answer (score 0):

First time, pick a random number from list, then hash the seed and save the pair in an array.

Afterwards, Hash seed and use it as a key in your array.

It's obviously a crappy solution but I think here it could do the trick.

Edit: just saw it's for same input list too. So hash the list and save that hash as well.

Comment: Two problems with this approach are that the probability of each item is not the same when the length of the list does not divide the number of possible hash values (2^64 on 64 bit platforms) and that `hash()` may not be random enough for the application.

Answer (score 0):

The following addresses the issue of the non-uniform probability distribution of Trefex's solution.

```py
import sys

def notrandom(choices, seed):
    n = len(choices)
    h_values = 2**sys.hash_info.width
    too_big = n * (h_values // n)
    depth = 1
    while True:
        h = hash(f'{depth}:{seed}')
        h = h % h_values  # map negative to positive
        if h < too_big:
            return choices[h%n]
        depth += 1
```

Switching to `hashlib` for a stronger hash function adds effort in supporting different types of seeds:

```py
import hashlib

def notrandom(choices, seed):
    if type(seed) is int:
        seed = '%x' %seed
    if type(seed) is str:
        seed = seed.encode('utf-8')
    if type(seed) is not bytes:
        raise ValueError('seed must be string, integer or bytes')
    n = len(choices)
    h_values = 2**256
    too_big = n * (h_values // n)
    depth = 1
    while True:
        h = hashlib.sha256(b'%d:%s' %(depth, seed))
        h = int(h.hexdigest(), 16)
        if h < too_big:
            return choices[h%n]
        depth += 1
```